# How to reopen Note 3 Samsung phone in case the password has been inserted wrongly and the phone is blocked

Tags: applications

the password of my note 3 phone has been inserted wrongly and the phone is already blocked and TalkBack has been turned on. is there any way to unblock it without losing information.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a Google account signed in to the device you can reset your password.

Or a better solution is to reset your Samsung account password. Assuming your device has Internet connection, you can unlock it from the account dashboard.